# Is it possible to make list of parallel call using spring integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have 5 different task these task must be executed parallely. This task implementation in 5 different classes.Now I need to invoke these 5 classes parallel. Also number of times task executed will differ for each invocation.

Lets say I have ProcessExecuoter class it will provide list of task needs to be executed.

//This list will change dynamically each invocation
List myTaskList = new ArrayList();

Based on some property value in MyTask I need to invoke corresponding TaskClass and collect the results.

I am using Spring Boot 1.2.4 and Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You need just send your tasks as payloads of messages to the `ExecutorChannel` and gather their result afterwards using `Aggregator` component.

All the necessary info you can find in the Reference Manual:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

Comment: does aggreagtor will be invoked all thread execution is complete?or do we need to set any property?I want make sure all my results are collected by aggregator.